# Selenium (Python) - Checking parameter next to the LABEL and insert the value OR select an option

Tags: python, selenium

IF would like to create a generic code (by using Selenium) which will look for the label, and the find next to the label input(OR select) tag and insert the value.

Main function:

```
for l in label: 
        try:
            xpathInput = "//label[contains(.,'{}')]/following::input".format(l)

            checkXpathInput, pathInput= check_xpath(browser,xpathInput)

            if checkXpathInput is True:
                pathInput.clear()
                pathInput.send_keys("\b{}".format(value))
                break

            for op in option:

                xpathSelect = "//label[contains(.,'{}')]/following::select/option[text()='{}']".format(l,op)
                checkXpathSelect, pathSelect= check_xpath(browser,xpathSelect)

                if checkXpathSelect is True:
                    pathSelect.click()
                    break


        except:
            print("Can't match: {}".format(l))
```

Path checker:

```
def check_xpath(browser,xpath):
    try:
        path = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True , path
```

What is the current issue?

- I need that if LABEL will be for example TITLE the code will check that there is NO `input` tag next to "Title" label and then he will go and check is there is the `select` tag next to the label "Title" and e.t.c....

In my current, he will find the label "Title" and then will fill in value to the first next input (which is incorrect as "Title" is using the SELECT tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd exploit the fact that `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list of found elements and empty lists are falsy. So you wouldn't need a try/except and a function which returns `bool` or `tuple` values (which is not the most optimal behavior).

It would be easier to give a good answer with some html source example but I assume what you'd like to do is this:

```py
def handle_label_inputs(label, value):
    # if there is a such label, this result won't be empty
    found_labels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[contains(.,"{}")]'.format(label))

    # if the list is not empty
    if found_labels:
        l = found_labels[0]
        # any options with the given value as text
        following_select_option_values = l.find_elements_by_xpath('./following::select//option[text()="{}"]'.format(value))
        # any inputs next to the label
        following_inputs = l.find_elements_by_xpath('./following::input')

        # did we find an option?
        if following_select_option_values:
            following_select_option_values[0].click()
        # or is there an input?
        elif following_inputs:
            in_field = following_inputs[0]
            in_field.clear()
            in_field.send_keys(value)
        else:
            print("Can't match: {} - {}".format(label, value))

driver.get('http://thenewcode.com/166/HTML-Forms-Drop-down-Menus')
handle_label_inputs('State / Province / Territory', 'California')
```

I don't know how tidy the page you are work with but if it is well done, then your label should have a `for="something"` attribute. If that is the case then you can simply find the label-related-element and find out if its tag is input (or select):

```
related_element_if_done_properly = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="{}"]'.format(label_element.get_attribute("for")))
if related_element_if_done_properly:
    your_element = related_element_if_done_properly[0]
    is_input = your_element.tagname.lower() == "input"
else:
    print('Ohnoes')
```

Comment: I really like your solution! In my solution I had an issue with -  `following::` as think about this  if `'//label[contains(.,"Title")]'` exists and next element will be `select`. So if we will use `'./following::input'` then the code will ignore `select` and will type the value to the next available input. But you solved it by checking for select element first )

Comment: Regarding `for` unfortunately websites with which I'm working are not using proper web development techniques.

Comment: I'm not sure if you will be able to answer this, but what you do when you have `select`, `input` AND AS WELL tickboxes??

Comment: Check the type of the input with `element.get_attribute("type")` if the result is "checkbox" then you have a checkbox input element. It could be more beneficial to pre-filter your input results with xpath. Instead of 

`following_inputs = l.find_elements_by_xpath('./following::input')` you could 

`following_inputs = l.find_elements_by_xpath('./following::input[@type="text"]')` and 

`following_checkboxes = l.find_elements_by_xpath('./following::input[@type="checkbox"]')`

Comment: Thank you! - if you will have any spare time, please have a look for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61501307/selelnium-python-date-of-birth-fields-by-using-label